# Three.js multiple uv maps

Tags: three.js

I have a .js mesh exported from blender with multiple uvs. When applying multiple materials, they all use the 1st uv on the mesh.

How can I assign a material to use X uv on mesh?

Regards

Comment: Hello, did you ever figure out a solution for this? Is it even possible with three.js?

Comment: No, searched high and low for months, eventually gave up :)